# Redirect to https version of the site?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, http-redirect

How do I keep the logic for `index.php` file but redirect from `http` to `https` version of the site?

My .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf8

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect simply needs to go first, *before* the existing internal rewrite.

For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # HTTP to HTTPS redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Internal rewrite
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I removed the `./` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. That's not required
(and doesn't really make sense in this context) and will be resolved away by the OS.

Also, consider removing the `<IfModule>` wrapper - it's not required here unless your code is being ported to multiple servers where mod_rewrite might not be enabled and your site is expected to work without it (although that seems unlikely). See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112602/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters Stack for more information regarding this: [Is Checking For mod_write Really Necessary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary)